# Why the wsdl importer generates strange objects?

Tags: wcf, delphi

I created a web service in .NET, that works fine on Silverlight and WPF. I want to do some try with Delphi XE4. My service is exposed with SOAP, so it's perfect for Rad Studio that have a automatic WSDL importer. My problem is that each type of my ws is represented with 2 classes.

the first is a complex type, which inherits from TRemotable:

```
// ************************************************************************ //
// XML       : MessageRecuperationSalaries, global, <complexType>
// Espace de nommage : http://XXX/XXX/XXX
// ************************************************************************ //
MessageRecuperationSalaries2 = class(TRemotable)
private
  FEtabCode: string;
  FEtabCode_Specified: boolean;
  FSalaries: ArrayOfSalarie;
  FSalaries_Specified: boolean;
  procedure SetEtabCode(Index: Integer; const Astring: string);
  function  EtabCode_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  procedure SetSalaries(Index: Integer; const AArrayOfSalarie: ArrayOfSalarie);
  function  Salaries_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
public
  destructor Destroy; override;
published
  property EtabCode: string          Index (IS_OPTN or IS_NLBL) read FEtabCode write SetEtabCode stored EtabCode_Specified;
  property Salaries: ArrayOfSalarie  Index (IS_OPTN or IS_NLBL) read FSalaries write SetSalaries stored Salaries_Specified;
end;
```

The second class inherits from the first one and doesn't contain any property:

```
// ************************************************************************ //
// XML       : MessageRecuperationSalaries, global, <element>
// Espace de nommage : http://XXX/XXX/XXX
// ************************************************************************ //
MessageRecuperationSalaries = class(MessageRecuperationSalaries2)
private
published
end;
```

Is there any option to directly generate only one class per type that inherits from TRemotable ? Or is my web service in cause ?

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: Well... it works. But it looks quite messy in my auto complete when I see two different classes for the same object. when I want to use the class without the number at the end, I have to cast it to the number terminated class